# how to search all public jsfiddle code?

Tags: jsfiddle

I visited the JSFiddle web site, was looking for an option to search all public fiddles. Could not find it. Does jsFiddle have a search facility?  I would like to search all public fiddles, looking for use of a specific API.

thanks,

Comment: any progress with this? I am facing this issue too

Comment: I've encountered the same :(, had to resort to google site search, for example if I want to search jsfiddle for angular rxjs I'd do following : angular rxjs _site_:https://jsfiddle.net/